# How to add class if browser window is bigger than 768

Tags: javascript, jquery, class, addition, window-resize

This has just been driving me bonkers. I've looked this up in several places and can't get it to work. All I want to do is add a "fancybox-iframe" class in a menu item (the last one, "contact us") as [shown here](http://www.ziptimberline.com), and so far, I can't get any code to work. I cannot do this in CSS, either. Can someone please help!!!??

Comment: Show some of the code you've tried. HTML and JS please.

Comment: why can't you do it in CSS? (visual stuff should be done in CSS normally)

Comment: @dandavis - Normally I would just use CSS, but the fancybox-iframe class is what triggers the iframe. I just to figure out a way to apply and remove the class because I don't it applied in smaller screens. Instead of an iframe, I just want it opening in a new window.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Could you do something like this?

```
if (window.innerWidth > 768) {
    document.getElementById('menu-item-34').className += ' fancybox-iframe';
}
```

(where `menu-item-34` is the id of the contact us button)

Comment: How does this have 3 upvotes?  It doesn't work.. use className instead of class.

Comment: @Josh - I tried it and it didnt work. I also have tried this:

if (window.innerWidth > 768) {
    document.getElementById('menu-item-34').addClass('fancybox-iframe');
}

Comment: from running the code in the console, it seems that the class is being added on to the element. is the fancybox-iframe style not being applied? Or is javascript code running that is dependent on that styling ran before the style is applied?

Comment: No, it's not being added at all. Like I said, I've tried everything I can think of and it simply isnt being added...

Comment: @BeverlyLodge after running the code I wrote, i see 'menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom menu-item-34 fancybox-iframe'. is that not what you see? where are you running the code?

Comment: @Josh - right in my header file. It's a stupid wordpress website, otherwise I'd just add a special class statically and call on it via css, but I can't. I have it up now exactly the way you wrote it and no joy :(

Answer (score 0):

I got it! Was missing a bit of love - I was being to literal, thanks Josh!

```
    <script>
    jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
        if (window.innerWidth > 768) {
        document.getElementById('menu-item-34').className +='fancybox-iframe';
       }
     });
    </script>
```